# Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder) is returning wrong value

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a UWP project, and wrote this code:

```
foreach (var foldertype in (Environment.SpecialFolder[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Environment.SpecialFolder)))
            {
                //string d = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
                var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(foldertype);
                var folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(path);
                StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder, folder.Path);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Opened the folder: {folder.DisplayName}");
                this.MenuFolderItems.Add(new MenuFolderItem(folder));
            }
```

It is supposed to enumerate all the special folders, and get their folder. However, while debugging, this is what happens:

```
foldertype = Desktop
path = "C:\\Users\\cuent\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\402b6149-1adf-4994-abc9-504111b3b972_a5s740xv383r0\\LocalState\\Desktop"
folder = [ERROR] System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)'
```

I do not know what is happening here, it seems to be appending the path to the installed location of the app. How do I fix this?

Expected output of `GetFolderPath()` is wherever the `Desktop` is, not the weird path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP apps are different from desktop applications when accessing the file system. UWP apps are running in the sandbox so there are limitations for UWP apps when trying to access the file system. You could check this document: [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). The document lists all the locations that UWP apps have permission to access.

Back to your scenario, what you need first is a **broadFileSystemAccess** restricted capability. This capability enables your app could use the `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync()` API with a Path parameter. This is mentioned in the last part of the document I posted above.

Then the second issue is the `Environment.GetFolderPath` API. It looks like the API will return a Path that points to a local folder inside the app's local folder. But there is no such desktop folder inside the app's local folder so you will get the FileNotFoundException. You might need to set the correct path by yourself like `C:\Users\your user name\Desktop`. After that, your code should be able to work correctly.